# How to pull data from a previous entry in a daily report?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro to simply a process that I do everyday at work. I pull data from the previous days and use it to generate the current day.

Currently the best way I've found to do what I want is to go into the code and manually change the parts that I need to.

```
`Sheets("Open PO ").Select
Sheets("Open PO ").Move Before:=Workbooks("random1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("66").Select
Range("Y5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'66'!R3C7:R142C25,18,FALSE)"
`
```

When the full code is run, it pulls from yesterday's (66 -> 6/6) data and uses the vlookup function to grab a chunk of data and paste it into the new day. And as long as I change the code manually, it works perfectly.

I'm just not sure if there is a way to not have to manually change it.

Comment: What is it that you need to change manually in order for it to work? In your code, you are only changing Range("Y5") and I guess that should be more than that?

Comment: I could post the entire thing, but that stuff is all things that work and are paste commands and filter commands. What's changing is the Sheets("XX").Select, and the "=VLOOKUP(RC7, 'XX'!R3C7:RXXXC25,18,FALSE)"  X being different numerical values for both the days and the number of lines to the bottom of my data

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, I'm assuming you get a new sheet for each day, and the rest is more static.

It might need some tweaks, but this should be a start:

```vb
Dim strSheet As String
strSheet = Day(Date) - 1
strSheet = strSheet & Month(Date)

Sheets("Open PO ").Move Before:=Workbooks("random1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets(strSheet).Range("Y5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC7,'" & strSheet & "'!R3C7:R142C25,18,FALSE)"
```